# галерея изображений в файловой системе java android

Tags: java, изображения, файловая-система

Привет всем, я делал некое подобие файлового менеджера и хотел сделать так, чтобы все изображения просматривались как небольшие иконки вот как-то так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но столкнулся с тем, что если отображать каждое изображение подряд загоняя его в Bitmap очень долго.
Отправьте пожалуйста литературу, где описывается как это реализовать для андроид, как в, например, этом проводнике, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, у всех изображений в галерее есть такая вещь как миниатюра, которая висит в кеше...

Comment: с миниатюрой получится, например, загрузить 100 картинок за короткий промежуток времени? Если да, то как ее достать?

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/thumbnails.php

Comment: Спасибки, посмотрю, сделаю, что смогу